# @Async on private class without @Autowired

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, asynchronous, autowired

I am trying to convert a small service to a library. I have a class X that makes calls to another class Y with async methods. The class Y with the async methods isn't meant to be exposed publicly. But as I understand, both classes need to be autowired for the async annotation to work.

An issue I see with that is that I would then need to put class Y in the class X constructor args or in a class Y setter in class X. Which wouldn't make sense if class Y is private and not meant to be exposed.

- Is there a way to use @Async without @Autowired?
- Is there a way to @Autowire a private class?

Comment: Well, I don't understand your question, please explain why Y should not be exposed and what you meant by that?

Comment: You can avoid exposing `Y` as public but keep it with "package-private" scope, in that way you can still call its methods from `X`, if you even can't do this then there are no options for what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Y is a package-private class not meant to be accessible to the person using the library.

Comment: `X` is not in same package as `Y`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying. They are in the same package, that works fine. My question is about @Autowired. My specific questions are bulleted at the bottom.

Comment: Then these annotations has nothing to do with class visibility and you can autowire Y in X and calls its methods.